# Selenium Как спарсить цену

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Доброй ночи. Хочу достать цену из вот из этого кусочка. Не могу понять какой метод лучше изпользовать.

```
price = br.find_elements_by_class_name("announcement-price__cost")
        for p in price:
            p = p.find_
            print("цена:", p)
```

Исходная страница.

```
<div class="announcement-price__cost ">
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
<meta itemprop="price" content="2300.00">
<b>€</b>2.300 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На странице может быть дестки элементов с таким же именем класса.
Лучше использовать find_by_xpath или find_by_css.
Лично я сам использовал find_by_xpath.

```
print(br.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='announcement-price__cost '").text) # должен вывести €2300.00
```

Comment: Для `find_by_css` выражение было бы: `"div.announcement-price__cost"`. Мне кажется, это проще выглядит чем xpath :)

Comment: @gil9red Да, вероятно, но я очень привык к xpath :)